# Error when creating new React Native Project

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface, yarnpkg

I am trying to create a new RN project in my new MAC . I have carefully followed the RN documentation and installed all the relevant applications.
When I try to create a new RN app, I incur with the following error. Please help[image]

Comment: sometimes silly internet connection problems or restrictions will cause errors, check your connection and use a VPN service to ensure that.

Comment: Try posting errors as text instead of image. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode